# How to change or add an image to staffdotnet.collapsiblepanel panel title?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, panel

I am working with WinForms and .Net 2.0 and I am using staffdotnet.collapsiblepanel dll to create a collapsible panel and I would like to add a back image to the panel title. 
I already can change back color in the panel title, but I don´t know how to do it with a image.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you can do this without making a minor change to the `StaffDotNot.CollapsiblePanel` library itself (found [here](http://collapsiblepanel.codeplex.com/)).

In `CollapsiblePanel.Designer.cs`, you'll see the following declarations at the end of the `partial class` declaration:

```
private System.Windows.Forms.Panel titlePanel;
private System.Windows.Forms.PictureBox togglingImage;
private System.Windows.Forms.ImageList collapsiblePanelImageList;
private System.Windows.Forms.Label lblPanelTitle;
```

You will need to modify the declaration `private System.Windows.Forms.Panel titlePanel;` to `public System.Windows.Forms.Panel titlePanel;`.  This will allow you to execute the following code from the test project included in the library download:

```
namespace StaffDotNet.CollapsiblePanel.Test
{
    public partial class frmTest : Form
    {
        public frmTest()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            this.collapsiblePanel1.titlePanel.BackgroundImage = Image.FromFile(@"GreenBubbles.jpg");
        }
    }
}
```

Using this example (substitute your own image), produced the following output:

[image: CollapsiblePanelTest - Form1]

This may not, however, be the optimum change you want to make (exposing the entire `titlePanel` object to your class).  Instead, it may make more sense to add a `property` to the CollapsiblePanel class definition which gets and sets the background image (while leaving the `titlePanel` member as `private`)

```
//CollapsiblePanel.cs
#region Properties
...
/// <summary>
/// Gets or sets the the background image used in the panel title
/// </summary>
[Category("Collapsible Panel")]
[Description("Gets or sets the background image used in the panel title")]
[DisplayName("Panel Title Background Image")]
public Image PanelBackgroundImage
{
    get { return titlePanel.BackgroundImage; }
    set { titlePanel.BackgroundImage = value; }
}
#endregion

//frmTest.cs
namespace StaffDotNet.CollapsiblePanel.Test
{
    public partial class frmTest : Form
    {
        public frmTest()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            this.collapsiblePanel1.PanelBackgroundImage = Image.FromFile(@"GreenBubbles.jpg");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You'll need to post the content of your exceptions in order to get any help.